# How to get website/store id in the cms blocks/pages Magento2

Tags: magento2, static-block, cms-block, cms-pages, websites

I'm checking this for long time but couldn't get this.I would like to display the website id through the magento cms block/pages.Without calling it from phtml's.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: All website ID or current?

Comment: Hi @RohanHapani .Thanks for the reponse.I need the current website id.But it would be helpful if you provide for all also.